# Uso de (int) en Java

Tags: java

Hace algún tiempo, me he fijado que en ocasiones aparece un tipo de dato de la siguiente forma.

```
(int)
```

La cual no entiendo para que esta hecho. Algunos de los casos en que lo he visto, viene siendo el siguiente:

```
suma = (int) (math.random * (4+3));
```

La pregunta es:

**¿Para qué se utiliza, cuál es su función o propósito?.**

Comment: Y cual es la diferencia entre casteo y parseo?

Comment: parseo implica que vas a quitar parte de una cadena o String. Casteo es convertir un objeto de una clase a otro objeto de otro tipo de clase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(int) es un casteo a un primitivo. Desde la JDK 1.5 ya no es necesario cuando casteas objetos Integer a primitivos (int) por el boxing y el unboxing. En tu caso lo que se está haciendo es un casteo de un primitivo double que devuelve math.Random a un primitivo int que no tiene valor decimal.
El casteo sirve para convertir un objeto o primitivo en otro.

Documentación [aquí](http://www.programacionfacil.com/java/operador_cast.html)

Comment: Y en caso que haya aplicado `suma = parseInt(math.random * (4+3));`, no seria lo mismo?

Comment: Integer.parseInt("..."); Integer es una clase que instancia es un objeto, int es un primitivo. ¿Tienes claro esos conceptos?

Comment: Entiendo que int es un primitivo, pero cuando coloco Integer.parseInt("..."); puedo hacer en esencia lo mismo que pasar Double a Int siempre y cuando este no tenga decimal

Answer (score 5):

Si miras la documentacion de [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random())  ves que la funcion devuelve `Double`.

`(int)` sirve para castear el `Double` a `int`  y asi quitar la parte decimal del numero.

Lo que comentas [en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64481/uso-de-int-en-java/64482#comment117020_64481) sobre diferencia entre Parsear y Castear seria basicamente que:

- Castear coge la representacion de esa variable y la representa con otro tipo. En este caso, `Double` a `Int`. No todos los tipos pueden ser casteados a otros, ya que su representacion interna de la variable no es compatible. Para ello está el parseo.
- Parsear seria algo más cerca a lo humano y convierte un tipo de variable a otra, como podria ser `String` a `Int` con el `parseInt`. Ej: `"7" -> 7`